# Getting notifications for Sitecore security patches

Tags: security

As we know Sitecore release security patches sometime which needs to be applied ASAP. Is there any way so that whenever any critical security patch is released by Sitecore, we will be notified?

Do we need to keep an eye on below URL everyday

https://kb.sitecore.net/SearchResults#fltr=t3

https://kb.sitecore.net/Security-RSS-Feed.aspx

OR

there is any kind of set up / notification we can enable

Comment: The RSS feed is the way I do it. It's integrated into Sitecore Slack #blogfeed channel.

Comment: that blog feed contains lots of other notifications, Is there any way to get /set up only critical security updates email notification. 
The only other way we think is creating a console app( batch job ) which will hit RSS feed during some interval, read text( Critical vulnerability ) from <description> element and then send email notification

Comment: That security feed you provided should do it. You can just use any RSS feed reader. I believe Microsoft outlook has that capability.

Comment: That's Correct @VincentLui MS Outlook has RSS Subscriptions feature. I added that RSS feed and got all latest emails from Security Bulletins but here I'm looking for a way so that an email should be triggered to myteam@company.com DL and everybody will be notified and take appropriate action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to inform you that the RSS feed is now obsolete and replaced by an email subscribe functionality on the https://support.sitecore.com/kb website.
Please have a look at this link to view the instructions on how to set it up: https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1000489

Summary:

> To subscribe to the Security Bulletins section:
>
> - Navigate to the Sitecore Knowledge Base homepage.
> - Log in to the
>   Sitecore Knowledge Base. Use the same credentials as for
>   https://profile.sitecore.net.
> - Click Subscribe just above Security
>   Bulletins section.

Comment: Thank you @Koen Heye. I did the same now

Answer (score 3):

To subscribe to Security Bulletin updates.

Go to https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_home

Click on Log In.
[image]

If you don't have an account, click "Need help in sign in" below the Sign in button. Then click "Don't have an account?".
[image]

Or check other options whichever is applicable in your case.

If you sign up then you may not get redirected to https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_home.

So separately go to https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_home

Click on Log In, and proceed with your new account credential. This time you should be redirected back to https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_home

Now, click on subscribe (grey text) as shown below.

[image]

Once subscribed it will be ticked and shows Subscribed.
[image]

Upon mouse hover, it shows the Unsubscribe link.
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this.

A note to Sitecore: when people (mostly with good computer skills) need to ask how to subscribe to security newsletter you are doing something very wrong.